# Convert char (Jan-23) to date (23-01)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a char field that I need to convert to a date. IE: Jan-23 to 23-1 or 2023-1.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your RDBMS,  how is the data actually stored  - please show examples.

Comment: SQL Server, field name is MonthOf and is setup as char(6).  The reason I am trying to convert these to a date (like 23-1) is to be able to sort them in order.  The below is what I currently get when sorting descending.


MonthOf
Apr-22
Apr-23
Aug-22
Dec-22
Feb-22
Feb-23
Jan-22
Jan-23
Jul-22
Jun-22
Mar-22
Mar-23
May-22
Nov-22
Oct-22
Sep-22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can convert month/year to date. It's incomplete without the day.

It does work like this

```
--SQL Server 2022
DECLARE @date CHAR(10) = 'Jan-23';
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT @date AsChar
     , CONCAT('01-', @DATE) StillChar
     , CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT('01-', @DATE)) AsDate
```

| AsChar | StillChar | AsDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-23 | 01-Jan-23 | 2023-01-01 |

Comment: This is correct, but could be dependent on the database locale... that should be "English". Sometimes it's safer to do a long `CASE WHEN` for the conversion.

Comment: The CONVERT option works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to fake it a bit. First turn it into a date, then format it.

`select format (cast('01'+ 'Jan 23' as date), 'yyyy-MM') as date`

that returns

`2023-01`

Or you could just write a case statement - `when 'JAN' then '01' ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `SQL CASE` to help format that char column to a sortable field.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Jan%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-01' 
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Feb%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-02'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Mar%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-03'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Apr%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-04'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'May%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-05'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Jun%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-06'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Jul%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-07'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Aug%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-08'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Sep%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-09'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Oct%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-10'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Nov%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-11'
     WHEN MonthOf LIKE 'Dec%' THEN trim(right(MonthOf, charindex('-', reverse(MonthOf)) -1)) + '-12'
END AS NewFormat, 
MonthOf FROM tblCharDate
ORDER BY NewFormat DESC
```

**Example**

| NewFormat | MonthOf |
| --- | --- |
| 23-07 | Jul-23 |
| 23-06 | Jun-23 |
| 22-12 | Dec-22 |
| 22-09 | Sep-22 |
| 22-08 | Aug-22 |
| 22-04 | Apr-22 |
| 22-02 | Feb-22 |